# Modify <div class="left-sidebar"> block for My Dashboard page

Tags: magento-1.9, sidebar

Following is a left side bar code when i am in "**My Dashboard**". I have to modify following style. Where is the file so i can modify the class.

```
<div class="block block-account">
  <div class="block-title"> <strong> <span>My Account</span> </strong> </div>
  <div class="block-content">
    <ul>
      <li class="current"> <strong>Account Dashboard</strong> </li>
      <li> <a href="http://localhost/my_theme/index.php/customer/account/edit/">Account Information</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="http://localhost/my_theme/index.php/customer/address/">Address Book</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="http://localhost/my_theme/index.php/sales/order/history/">My Orders</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="http://localhost/my_theme/index.php/sales/billing_agreement/">Billing Agreements</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="http://localhost/my_theme/index.php/sales/recurring_profile/">Recurring Profiles</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="http://localhost/my_theme/index.php/review/customer/">My Product Reviews</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="http://localhost/my_theme/index.php/tag/customer/">My Tags</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="http://localhost/my_theme/index.php/wishlist/">My Wishlist</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="http://localhost/my_theme/index.php/oauth/customer_token/">My Applications</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="http://localhost/my_theme/index.php/newsletter/manage/">Newsletter Subscriptions</a> </li>
      <li class="last"> <a href="http://localhost/my_theme/index.php/downloadable/customer/products/">My Downloadable Products</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What class do you want to edit?

Comment: @Mayers : actually i wanted file location of **My Dashboard**. You can see right answer of Marius below. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Marius definitely beat me to it, make sure you don't hard-code any `li` in this file though, the right way to add/remove/modify elements is done via the layout files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template that renders this html is `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml`.
If there is no such file in your theme copy it from `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml` and do your changes in the copy.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really enough info to know for sure. 
But your css files should be located in,

```
 skin/frontend/default/my_theme/css or skin/frontend/my_theme/my_theme/css
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bryanlittlefield/Magento-Remove-Dashboard-Links

This must be thirty characters by now?